# append blade file using jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

//this is my code..

```
<select class="custom-select" id="inputGroup">
  @include('admin.orders.partials.loop');
</select>
```

//jquery

```
$.get("admin.orders.partials.loop", function(data){
    $('#inputGroup').append(data);
});
```

//what's inside the include

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
  <option value="{{ $product->id }}">{{ $product->ProdName }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: So what's your problem? Please get straight to the point if you are straight [ask]

Comment: my bad, I need to dynamically append  the "@include('admin.orders.partials.loop');" line using jquery.

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question and try to rephrase it, currently it is not clear what the problem is.